# LuaTeX gets stuck when "." is added to pattern-expression

Tags: luatex, lua

today on SE I got inspired to try LuaTeX.

I'm facing a problem where the compilation process stalls at some point if I add a single "." to a pattern matching expression.

In short, this works:

```
line = string.gsub ( line , "^(%s*)"    ,   "%1" )
```

this doesn't:

```
line = string.gsub ( line , "^(%s*)."   ,   "%1" )
```

(I know this pattern doesnt make toooo much sense, but it's a reduced version of a longer expression)

Compilation stalls at:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238) 
restricted \write18 enabled.
(./mwe4.tex 
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
[...]
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/cctb.lua))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase-mcb.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/mcb.lua))))  (./mwe4.aux))
*
```

A full MWE is here (the critical line being #6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}

\begin{luacode}
function replacetext2 ( line )    
line = string.gsub ( line , "^(%s*)"    ,   "%1" )
return ( line )
end 
\end{luacode}

\newenvironment{haystack}{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
      "process_input_buffer",
      replacetext2, "replacetext2")}}{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
      "process_input_buffer",
      "replacetext2")}}

\begin{document}
\begin{haystack}
a
 b
\end{haystack}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the exact same behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern `^(%s*).` in

```
line = string.gsub ( line , "^(%s*)."    ,   "%1" )
```

looks for any white space (can be empty) at the begin of line, followed by one character (`.`). This is replaced by the white space (`%1`) and the matched non-white-space character is removed. Therefore LuaTeX will no longer see `\end{haystack}`, but `end{haystack}` and keeps looking for the end of the environment.

The example with some debug output to show the line in brackets, before and after the substitution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode,luatexbase}

\begin{luacode}
function replacetext2 ( line )
  texio.write_nl('')
  texio.write('[', line, '] --> [')
  line = string.gsub ( line , "^(%s*)."    ,   "%1" )
  texio.write(line, "]")
  texio.write_nl('')
  return ( line )
end
\end{luacode}

\newenvironment{haystack}{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
      "process_input_buffer",
      replacetext2, "replacetext2")}}{%
  \directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
      "process_input_buffer",
      "replacetext2")}}

\begin{document}
\begin{haystack}
a
 b
\end{haystack}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
[a] --> []
[ b] --> [ ]
[\end{haystack}] --> [end{haystack}]
[\end{document}] --> [end{document}]
```

If you only want to remove a real dot at the beginning of a line, then the dot needs to be escaped as magic character `%.`, since the pure dot `.` means any character.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed analysis. I wasn't even aware that the \end{..} and \begin{..} were also passed on to replacetext2

Comment: @sheß - The `process_input_buffer` callback operates at a very early stage, before TeX does much of its usual work. Once `replacetext2` is activated (via `\begin{haystack}`), it continues to operate until the end of the `haystack` environment is encountered. However, because of the way you wrote `replacetext2`, the `\` (backslash) in `\end{haystack}` got removed (unintentionally, of course). Because `end{haystack}` (without the backslash) does *not* terminate the `haystack` environment, `replacetext2` was not removed from the `process_input_buffer` callback, leading to all sorts of havoc.